# R, using for loop, how can I generate new variables with different results according to different targeted data frame

Tags: r

R, using for loop,  how can I generate new variables with different results according to the different targeted data frame.

For example, I have data-frames named as  Version1, version2, version3,version4, version5,version6.

For detail in versions:

Version1:
Name  Age  HW_score Midterm Final Gender Year_in_school
AA    21      90     90       90    F         1
AB    20      80     88       100   F         1
AC    22      85     95       97    M         1
AD    21      88     99       96    M         1

Version2:
Name  Age  HW_score Midterm Final Gender Year_in_school
AE    23      90     70       90    F         1
BB    20      84     88       90    M         1
DC    21      85     90       97    M         1
AD    22      88     94       96    M         2

Version3:
Name  Age  HW_score Midterm Final Gender Year_in_school
AZ    23      90     70       94    F         2
CB    20      89     88       90    M         3
FC    21      78     90       97    F         1
AA    24      89     96       96    M         2

similar for version4,5,6

If I have to select the row where the age is 21.

Q1:
How can I  create variables named as result_[the name of the data frame]: result_version1, result_version2, result_version3, result_version4,result_version5,result_version6. And store the results of each data frame into the new variables.

The desired results are

result_version1:
Name  Age  HW_score Midterm Final Gender Year_in_school
AA    21      90     90       90    F         1
AD    21      88     99       96    M         1

result_version2:
Name  Age  HW_score Midterm Final Gender Year_in_school
DC    21      85     90       97    M         1

result_version3:
FC    21      78     90       97    F         1

similar for result_version4,5,6

Q2:
What if storing results from different data frame into one variable:

Desired output:

result_version_all
Name  Age  HW_score Midterm Final Gender Year_in_school
AA    21      90     90       90    F         1
AD    21      88     99       96    M         1
DC    21      85     90       97    M         1
FC    21      78     90       97    F         1

How should write the code in R using for loop to have the above output?
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put all the dataframes in a list and subset them using `lapply`.

```
result <- lapply(mget(paste0('Version', 1:6)), function(x) subset(x, Age == 21))
```

`result` has list of dataframes with output. To get them as separate dataframes use `list2env`

```
names(result) <- paste0('result_',paste0('Version', 1:6))
list2env(result, .GlobalEnv)
```

Combine all the list of dataframes into one result.

```
result_version_all <- do.call(rbind, result)
```

Comment: Thanks. It succeeds. And I want to know what if I need to drop the second row for each data frame and store it in results. How, the  lapply(mget(paste0('Version', 1:6)), function(x) subset(x, Age == 21)) should revise?

Comment: And what if now, version1 through 6 are stored in a single data frame named as version_all. And I want to separate them into a smaller data frame, according to different conditions. Eg, data frame  version_male if gender = male, version_female if gender = female, or  version_y20 if age =20,  version_y21 if age =21, .... (suppose there are total 6 different ages).  Can that be done in a single line of the lapply code?  Thanks!

Comment: @Sienna97 Please don't extend your question in comments. If you have additional question you can add it as a new question. To drop second row you can do `result <- lapply(mget(paste0('Version', 1:6)), function(x) subset(x, Age == 21)[-2, ])` Or `result <- lapply(mget(paste0('Version', 1:6)), function(x) subset(x[-2, ], Age == 21))` based on how you want your final output.

Comment: Sorry, I will ask the extended question as a new question. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following code, it does not involve a for loop though.

Q1    `result_version1 = Version1[which(Version1$Age == 21),] # repeat for all versions`

Q2    `result_version_all = rbind(result_version1,result_version2,...result_version6)`

Comment: Thanks, it works. But if there's a large number of data frames, eg over 2000. This process will result in many lines of code.